# How can I only show distinct data from database where user_id is the same as current user in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, eloquent

I have a user table and position table.

**Position Table** contains

```
Schema::create('positions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name_position');            
        $table->boolean('is_head');
        $table->string('name_department');
        $table->boolean('is_top');
        $table->string('top_name_department');
        $table->string('position_report');
        $table->integer('assigned_emp_id');            
        $table->timestamps();
```

Positions Controller contains

```
public function createorg()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id);  
    return view('positions.createorg')->with('positions',$user->positions);
}
```

Blade contains

```
<select id="name_department" name="name_department">
        <option value="0">Please select a department</option>
        @foreach($positions as $row)
        {
            <option value="name_department">{{$row->name_department}}</option>
        }
        @endforeach
        
    </select>
```

My FE is showing

```
<select id="name_department" name="name_department">
        <option value="0">Please select a department</option>
                    {
        <option value="name_department">Company</option>
        }
                    {
        <option value="name_department">Finance</option>
        }
                    {
        <option value="name_department">Finance</option>
        }
                    
 </select>
```

So my problem here is I do not want to show duplicate departments since the department is only one. But in my position table, I have multiple data entry with the same department. How can I achieve it?

[image]

Comment: how about using `$user->positions->distinct()`

Comment: I think it will only give me one data line. I will try. One user will add many positions in the same department in positions table.

Comment: If you are only interested in name_department key only, then use groupBy from 
 laravel collection, `$user->positions->groupBy('name_department');`, also if you use `$user->positions->groupBy('name_department')->all();` it would send an array grouped by your name_department, then in your view, you can just simply use `@foreach(array_keys($positions) as $row)`

Comment: `public function createorg()    
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);         
        return view('positions.createorg')->with('positions',$user->positions->groupBy('name_department'));
    }` I got this error   Exception
Property [name_department] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: C:\wamp64\www\myproject\resources\views\positions\createorg.blade.php)

Comment: if it is inside then use . syntax, eg `positions.name_department`, see the structure of your `$user->positions` using `dd();`

Comment: @bhucho thanks for your help. I am beginner here and cannot follow up quite well with your reply. I follow the second answer and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can create another variable with the department names from the $user->positions and pass it along to the view

```php
public function createorg()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    $departments = $user->positions->pluck('name_department')->unique();

    return view('positions.createorg', [
        'positions' => $user->positions, 
        'departments' => $departments]
    );
}
```

Then use $departments in blade view to populate select options

```
<select id="name_department" name="name_department">

    <option value="0">Please select a department</option>

    @foreach($departments as $department)
        
        <option value="name_department">{{$department}}</option>
       
    @endforeach
        
</select>
```

Or you can do it in blade view directly without passing $departments from controller

```
<select id="name_department" name="name_department">

    <option value="0">Please select a department</option>

    @foreach($positions->pluck('name_department')->unique() as $department)
        
        <option value="name_department">{{$department}}</option>
       
    @endforeach
        
</select>
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Please remember to accept/upvote the answer for the benefit of subsequent visitors to the post

Comment: for option 1, I got error but after removing  `'positions' => $positions,` in controller. it works.  But i need positions as well so I tried option 2 and it is easy to understand for me as well.

Comment: Yeah sorry my bad it should have been `'positions' => $user->positions,` instead. If you replace `'positions' => $positions,` with  ` 'positions' => $user->positions, `  even option 1 will work. You may try it just for confirmation sake

Comment: @Donkarnash you write nice answers, always good to follow, learning from my mistakes :)

Comment: Thanks @bhucho. We learn from each other thats the way to grow I believe